# Relativistic Limit

Tags: special-relativity

Excuse me.

I have a problem about double limit, namely, Relativistic Limit.

Let $c$ is positive real constant.  Calculate
\begin{equation}
\lim_{v\to c}\lim_{V\to c}\frac{v - V}{1 - vV/c^2}.
\end{equation}
I have tried in many times, but I fail.

Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$
\lim_{v\rightarrow c }\>  \lim_{V\rightarrow c }\frac{v-V}{1-vV/c^2} =  \lim_{v\rightarrow c }\frac{v-c}{1-v/c}= \lim_{v\rightarrow c }-c =-c.
$$